# If Else not running

Tags: c, if-statement

I fixed the issues you guys pointed out (thanks btw!) but now it's giving me an infinite loop.
I don't see why. My mortgageleft is getting decreased by the monthlypayment every time the while loop runs...

```
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(){
    float MortgageLeft, InterestRate, MonthlyPayment, MonIntRate, AmountOwed;
    int Month=0;

    printf("What is the value left on the mortgage?\n");
    scanf("%f", &MortgageLeft);

    printf("What is the annual interest rate of the loan, in percent?\n");
    scanf("%f", &InterestRate);

    printf("What is the monthly payment?\n\n");
    scanf("%f", &MonthlyPayment);

    MonIntRate= (InterestRate/12)/100;

    printf("Month\t\t Payment\t\t Amount Owed");

    while (MortgageLeft>0){
        MortgageLeft=(MortgageLeft*MonIntRate)+MortgageLeft;
        if(MortgageLeft>MonthlyPayment)
        {
            MortgageLeft=MortgageLeft-MonthlyPayment;    
            Month++;
            printf("%d\t\t %.2f\t\t %.2f", Month, MonthlyPayment, MortgageLeft);
        }

}
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should include a tag which language you are using.

Comment: you are not changing `MortgageLeft` value. when will that `while` loop exit?

Comment: C is not Python.  Your `while` loop is infinite because the `if` is not part of the loop and the nothing in the (one statement) loop body changes the value of `MortgageLeft`.  An automatic indenter (code formatter) would show this.

Comment: Put a couple `printf`s in the code. One at the beginning of the `while` loop, and another at the beginning of the `if` statement.

Comment: @Mr.Delicious: Don't change the question by editing the code, that invalidates the answers. Ask a new question instead.

Answer (score 2):

Your `while` loop lacks any brackets, so it only executes the very next statement `AmountOwed=(MortgageLeft*MonIntRate)+MortgageLeft;` in the loop, which never changes the loop condition. The infinite loop means you never reach the `if`/`else`.

Answer (score 2):

You won't leave the While loop until MortgageLeft is less than or equal to zero. At what point inside that While loop is the value of MortgageLeft getting smaller?

For your updated question, what happens when MortgageLeft is less than or equal to MonthlyPayment, but is still greater than zero?

Comment: Thanks I see that now.

Answer (score 0):

In the following code, either you are missing curly braces for While loop and/or missed to modify value of `MortgageLeft`

```
 while (MortgageLeft>0)
        AmountOwed=(MortgageLeft*MonIntRate)+MortgageLeft;
        if(AmountOwed>MonthlyPayment)
        {
            AmountOwed=AmountOwed-MonthlyPayment;    
            Month++;
            printf("%d\t\t %.2f\t\t %.2f", Month, MonthlyPayment, AmountOwed);
        }
        else
        {
            Month++;
            printf("%d\t\t %f\t\t 0", Month, AmountOwed);
    }
```